# Submitting request to https returns http

Tags: django, angular, http, https

I'm creating and angular app that uses a django backend accessed as a Api. The link for my backend is https, and one of its main purposes is to act as a database for image storage.

I am trying to grab the URLs in the backend by using http calls from my front end. It's not working because the GET calls only return Http urls not Https. This means that when the front end tries to access the url it can't be found :(

Does anyone know how I can change my code so Https is returned or can suggest me some type of workaround?

Here is my API call:

```
export class ImageService {
  baseUrl = 'https://link.com'; 

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getBebidas() {
    return this.httpClient.get(`${this.baseUrl}/bebidas`);
}
```

And this is an example of the return (an array of json objects):

```
[{image_url: "http://link.com/image}]
```

Comment: What backend returns is determined by backend code. Can you show it?

Comment: The back end is actually being developed by someone else, but the problem would probably exist in ROOT_URLCONF or something needs to be added from the django.http module? But honestly, I am a very new developer so I am open to any ideas!

Comment: As it is now, it's unsolvable. Think that way: you're not the author of that code which is returning undesirabe response. You're only interfacing with it. So there's nothing you can do from your end to fix it, and without access to it trying to tell how it should be fixed is nothing more than guessing.

Comment: The backend developer was able to fix it. Thanks so much for helping me figure out what the problem was :)